# How to Debug IE8 "Abort Script Execution?" Alert

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8

The website runs well on all modern browsers. However, we try to achieve (for the moment) IE8 compatibility.

Now, we get the following error alert:

> Abort script execution? The scripts loaded might slow down...etc [Yes] [No]

---

**How can I find out which script is causing this?**

---

*Thank you*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use IE-11. It has emulator to check your website on older versions (inside developers tool). if an error occur in some stage it shows in console.

Comment: Thank you. This is in general a very good solution which I also used a few times. However, the problem is that this error only shows up in the very native IE8, but not in the IE-8 simulation of IE11.

Comment: hmm. this is kind of odd situation then?. im just go with manual debugging. disable some scripts and run, kind of approach. don't bother with tools :P

Comment: Yes, this approach actually solved the problem. Also it was due to a very slow testing machine (which still had installed IE8 native : )